# How to convert multipoint layer to polyline layer in QGis

Tags: qgis, line, multipoint

How can I convert a multipoint layer to polylines layer in QGis. I am looking for a tool equal as the GeoWizards (convert > Multipoint to polyline) for ArcGis.

Answer (score 1):

In the processing toolbox, you can run the SAGA module `Convert points to line(s)`.

You can choose an order column, and a separation column.

Comment: Dear AndreJ, thank you but it doesnt work. It may work for points but I have a multipoint layer that I need to convert to polylines. What I have is a  multipoint layer, with hundreds registers, where each register (each line) is a path (formed by diferent geographic points but all of these points have the same date and the same ship identification. What I need is to convert these multipoints to polylines (one polyline for date and  ship identification).

Comment: If what you have are multipoints with the same attributes, how do you define the point's order to create each polyline?